# PLSQL - help on my regex phone number with area code

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have difficulties to find the right regex under PL/SQL, but my regex is normally good

I have a phone number like this :

> +44 (0)22 3333 4444 from the text that should not be there

And I want to get this:

> +4402233334444

So I made the following regex:

> /[^+\d]|\s/g

It works very well on the site https://regexr.com/ but not in my PL/SQL query, it gives me the same result

I tried to use the oracle doc, but without success
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\d` and other shorthand character classes should not be used inside a bracket expression.

You can use

```sql
SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    '+44 (0)22 3333 4444',
    '[^+0-9]',
    ''
) As Result FROM dual;
```

where `[^+0-9]` matches any char other than `+` and a digit.

See the [DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=52868048cb0565ee83f45310a290ac57).

Note that `[^+0-9]` already matches any whitespace chars since non-digit chars other than `+` also match what `\s` matches, so you can safely omit the `|\s` from your regex.

Comment: My god, I tried to make it complicated! It was in front of my eyes

Thanks for your help!